# How hard is it to implement a temporal tagger?

Tags: nlp

I would like to implement a temporal tagger of my own just for my experience. I just want to know how hard is it to implement a good temporal tagging system by myself (only me) and what kind of an approach should I take.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to replicate recent work by Angeli, Manning, and Jurafsky in NAACL 2012, "Parsing Time: Learning to Interpret Time Expressions" and see where you get.
http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=angeli+manning+jurafsky+parsing+time&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C33&as_sdtp=

Short of wasting a ton of time writing regular expressions every which way 'til Sunday (and still probably not covering expressions like "'til Sunday"), that's probably the best anybody has done.  If you're going to go the regexp route, at least try improving something like Ruby's date module or some other free software date/time parser, so others can benefit from your work, and so you don't have to reinvent *every* wheel.

I'd love to hear about where you take this, if you actually do work on it.